# Class not found com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.sqlserverdriver

Tags: java, sql, netbeans, maven

A ver si me podéis ayudar, estoy desesperado.
He creado una aplicación con maven java mediante netbeans. Esta aplicación dispone de una conexión a SQL Server para las consultas a base de datos.
Cuando estoy haciendo el debuug o ejecuto la aplicación desde netbeans todo funciona bien, en cambio cuando compilo la aplcación y la ejecuto me lanza el error de "Class not found com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.sqlserverdriver".
Ya he probado:

- Añadir las variables de entorno PATH.
- Añadir los dll de mssql-jdbc_auth tanto en system32 como en syso64.
- Compilar con JDK 15 y JDK16.

Aquí dejo mi pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>ControlPresencia</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <targetPath>META-INF</targetPath>
                <directory>src</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>jax-ws-catalog.xml</include>
                    <include>wsdl/**</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsimport</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <wsdlUrls>
                                <wsdlUrl>https://meta3998.visualtime.net/vtlivebusiness/datalink/externalapi.asmx?WSDL</wsdlUrl>
                            </wsdlUrls>
                            <packageName>webServiceVisualTime</packageName>                       
                            <staleFile>${project.build.directory}/jaxws/stale/externalapi.asmx.stale</staleFile>
                        </configuration>
                        <id>wsimport-generate-externalapi.asmx</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>                
                <configuration>
                    <sourceDestDir>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/jaxws-wsimport</sourceDestDir>
                    <xnocompile>true</xnocompile>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <extension>true</extension>
                    <catalog>${basedir}/src/jax-ws-catalog.xml</catalog>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>         
            <configuration>
              <archive>
                <manifest>
                  <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                  <mainClass>VISTA.Presencia</mainClass>
                </manifest>
              </archive>
            </configuration>
          
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.metro</groupId>
            <artifactId>webservices-rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.metro</groupId>
            <artifactId>webservices-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scream3r</groupId>
            <artifactId>jssc</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency> 
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>9.2.1.jre15</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Dejo también el codigo de la clase conexion:

```
public Connection connecta() {                  
    Connection connexio = null;    
        url="jdbc:"+rdbms+"://MGSGESTION;databaseName="+ db +";integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=NativeAuthentication";    
        try {                    
                    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"); // Carrying  the driver
                    connexio = DriverManager.getConnection(url);                   
                    System.out.println ( "Conexión realizada" );            
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){           
            e.printStackTrace();
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e, "ERROR EN CLASS", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        catch (SQLException e ){            
            e.printStackTrace();
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e, "ERROR EN SQL", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }       
        return connexio;
    }
```

Comment: asegúrate de que el `sqljdbc.jar` esté dentro del path.

Comment: Si, esta dentro, lo he copiado dentro de todos los paths configurados.... y nada.

Comment: Muestra tu `pom.xml` a ver si podemos ayudarte mejor. Si tienes bien configurado el entorno Maven el `.jar` que se genera cuando compilas el proyecto debería incluir todas las librerías necesarias para que el programa se ejecute sin ningún problema. Indica también en la pregunta el tipo de compilación que estás ejecutando, el `.jar` que estás ejecutando (carpeta donde se encuentra), etc. El asunto no va de agregar a mano ciertos archivos en el dispositivo que ejecutará tu aplicación (eso sería poco práctico), uno de los propósitos de usar Maven es evitar eso precisamente.

Comment: Hola, antes que nada gracias por la respuesta. Adjunto en el post el codigo pom.xml.
El .jar que estoy ejecutando se encuentra en la ubicación donde lo deja netbeans al compilar:  "C:\Users\vribes\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ControlPresencia\target"

Comment: ¿Cómo se llama ese jar exactamente?

Comment: La aplicacion se llama ControlPresencia-1.0-SNAPSHOT

Comment: Alguien que pueda ayudar? Ya no se que hacer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

al final mediante la ayuda de Roberto E Moran me percate de que no se estaban incluyendo las dependencias dentro del jar compilado, cosa que no tiene ningun sentido ya que no estoy indicando  en el pom.xml y deberia de compilarlo automaticamente. Probe configurando el  en modo compile y tampoco.
Googleando encontre un plugin para ensamblar las librerias dentro del jar, adjunto aqui el codigo que me ha servido a mi por si le pasa a alguien en un futuro no pierda tantos dias como yo.
Esto se debe de inlcuir en el pom.xml como plugin:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>            
                    <descriptorRefs>
//Sufijo que se le agregara al fichero JAR ejecutable
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>           
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
//Aqui se establece el nombre de la clase principal
                            <mainClass>com.MainClass</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase> 
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para autenticar contra la base de datos utilizando el usuario de windows debes de colocar el archivo `mssql-jdbc_auth.dll` dentro de la carpeta de la JDK `jdk<vesion>\bin` y `jdk<vesion>\include`. Esto se suele utilizar con usuarios de AciveDirectory así que verifica que tu usuario esta en dominio y que se le ha dado el permiso de acceso a la base de dato en SQLServer.

Otra opción segun la flexibilidad que tengas en el proyecto es crear un nuevo usuario y contraseña dentro de la base de datos para omitir la dll y autenticar como lo harías normalmente, otro punto a tener en cuenta es que desde un contenedor linux no puedes utilizar la autenticación por usuario de sesión solo con usuario y contraseña.

Comment: Hola Roberto, he intentado lo que has dicho. 
He creado un nuevo usuario en la base de datos para conectar directamente sin tener que pasar por ActiveDirectory y pasa exactamente lo mismo, cuando estoy en modo debug funciona correctamente pero cuando compilo el .jar lanza el mismo error indicando que no encuentra el Driver.

Comment: Es raro, prueba abrir el Jar de tú proyecto con WinRAR y confirma que la librería de mssql-jdbc se encuentra dentro del proyecto compilado.

Comment: Hola. He abierto con winrar el proyecto y efectiamente no se encuentra la libreria, podria ser que tuviera algo mal en el pom.xml pero no veo que puede ser ya que las dependencias paracen bien formuladas.

Comment: Yo pienso lo mismo no veo nada que pueda decir que esta evitando incluir la libreria, prueba colocar explícitamente el scope de esa librería  `<scope>compile</scope>` recompila el proyecto y verifica.